# adding information to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Before i proceed, i would like to say i am a beginner and i am trying to validate a form using ajax, for username availability. Validations are done. But, everytime the page gets redirected to the form action page (Even if there are errors). I want, if there are errors i get a alert message and if no errors then data is written to db. I have been trying this for quite some time but i think i messed up and i dont understand what is wrong. Please,  correct my mistakes. I am just trying to learn. What i am doing wrong here and what should i do?

registration.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>-->
    <title>Using AJAX</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#txtUsr').on('keyup', function(){
                var username=$("#txtUsr").val();
                var user_name_avail_result=$('.check');
                var userCorrect=true;
                if(username.length>2)
                {
                    $.ajax({        
                    type : 'POST',
                    cache:'false',
                    data : "username="+username,
                    url  : "usr_available.php",
                    beforeSend: function()
                    {
                        user_name_avail_result.fadeIn(1000).html('<img src="green_ajax-loader.gif" /> ');
                    },
                    success: function(responseText) {
                    if(responseText == 200)
                    {
                        $(".check").html("<img src='available.png'/><span style='color:#59b200;'>Username available</span>");
                    }
                    else if(responseText ==201)
                    {
                        $(".check").html("<img src='not-available.png'/><span style='color:#ff0033;'>Username not available</span>");
                        userCorrect=false;
                    }
                    else if(responseText==202)
                    {
                        $(".check").html("Username too short");
                        userCorrect=false;
                    }
                }
            });
            }
            else
            {
            user_name_avail_result.html('<span style="color:#e50000;">Name too Short!</span>');
            userCorrect=false;
            }   
        if(username.length == 0) {
            user_name_avail_result.html("");
            userCorrect=false;
        }
        var exprUsr=/(^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*([._-][a-z0-9]+){3,15})$/;
        if(!exprUsr.test(username))
        {
            userCorrect=false;
        }
    });
    $("#txtPwd").on('keyup',function(){
                var regPwd=/^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,12})+$/;
                var passTxt=$('#txtPwd').val();
                var pwdCorrect=true;
                if(!regPwd.test(passTxt))
                {
                    $(".chkPwd").html('<div style="width:200px; height:80px; margin-left:190px; margin-top:-20px; text-align:left;"><span style="font-size:small; color:#ff0033;">Password must contain at least one digit, one lowercase, one uppdercase and one special character</span></div>');
                    pwdCorrect=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $(".chkPwd").html("");
                }
                if(passTxt.length==0)
                {
                    $(".chkPwd").html("You Must Enter a Password");
                    pwdCorrect=false;
                }

            });

    $("#txtUsr,#txtPwd,#txtMob").keydown(function(e) { <!-- Dont allow users to enter spaces for their username and passwords and Mobile Number-->
        if (e.which == 32) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    $("#txtMob").keydown(function(e){<!--No other keys except number keys and backspace and tab work-->
        if(e.which==8 || e.which==9)
            return true;
        if(e.which<48 || e.which>57)
            return false;
    });
    $("#txtMob").on('keyup',function(){
        var exprMob=/^[789]\d{9}$/;
        var mobNum=$('#txtMob').val();
        var mobCorrect=true;
        if(!exprMob.test(mobNum))
        {
        if(mobNum.length<10)
        {
            $("#span3").html("Number must be minimum 10 characters long");
            mobCorrect=false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#span3").html("Number in wrong format");
            mobCorrect=false;
        }
        }
        else
        {
        $("#span3").html("");
        }
    }); 
        function Validation(n){
        if(userCorrect==false || pwdCorrect==false || window.mobCorrect==false)
        {
            alert("One or More field(s) is/are unfinished/empty. Please re-check.");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clearAll()
        {
            document.getElementById("txtUsr").value="";
            document.getElementById("txtPwd").value="";
            document.getElementById("txtMob").value="";
        }
    </script>
    <style>
    .chkPwd
    {
        margin-left:80px;
    }
    .check
    {
        margin-left:90px;       
    }
    .form
   {
        margin:auto;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Consolas;
        font-size:medium;
   }
   .texts
   {
        font-family:Consolas;
   }
   #userDiv
    {
    background-color:#ccdbff;
    height:320px;
    width:500px;
    border-radius:10px;
    opacity:0.8;
   }
   #mainBody
   {
      background-color:#7a7acc;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="form" id="mainBody">
    <h1 style="color:#bfff00;">Registration</h1><br>
    <form class="form" id="regForm" action="registration_success.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return Validation(this)">
    <div class="form" id="userDiv"><br><br>
    Username: <input class="texts" id="txtUsr" name="txtUsr" type="text" placeholder="Type user name here" autocomplete="off" maxlength="15" autofocus="autofocus" title="Please dont enter an aweful username!"/><br>
    <span id="span1" class="check" style="font-size:small; color:"></span>
    <br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="txtPwd" class="texts" name="txtPwd" placeholder="Type password here" autocomplete="off" maxlength="12" title="Password must contain at least one digit, one lowercase, one uppdercase and one special character"/><br>
    <span id="span2" class="chkPwd" style="font-size:small; color:red;">Min 6 and Max 12 Characters</span><br>
    MobileNo.:<input type="text" maxlength="10" id="txtMob" class="texts" name="txtMob" placeholder="Enter your mobile number here" autocomplete="off" title="Please enter numbers only"/><br>
    <span id="span3" class="chkMob" style="font-size:small; margin-left:10px; color:#ff0033; font-size:small;"></span><br>
    <pre class="texts"> <input type="button" value="Back To LogIn" id="register" class="texts" name="register"/>   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="texts" name="send"/>   <input type="button" value="Reset" id="clear" onclick="clearAll()"/></pre>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

user_available.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST'){
    if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
            mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die ("Oops! Server not connected"); // Connect to the host
            mysql_select_db("db_chkAJAX") or die ("Oops! DB not connected"); // select the database
        // Check for the username posted
            $username= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]); // Get the username values & prevent SQL-Injection
            if(strlen($username)>2){
            $check_query= mysql_query('SELECT Username FROM LoginRecord WHERE Username = "'.$username.'" ') or die("Cannot get data from table"); // Check the database
            if(mysql_num_rows($check_query)<1){ // check num or rows 0 or greater than 0
                echo 200;//Username doesnot exist in database
                }
            else{
                echo 201;//Username exists in databse
                }
            } else {
                echo 202;//Too short username
                }
        }
        mysql_close($link);
        return;//Stop execution
    }   
?>
```

registration_success.php

```
<!--Writing to the database-->
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send']) && !empty($_POST['txtUsr']) && !empty($_POST['txtPwd']) && !empty($_POST['txtMob']))
    {
    //Connecting to databse
        $usr_name=test_input(strtolower($_POST['txtUsr']));
        $pwd=$_POST['txtPwd'];
        $mob=test_input($_POST['txtMob']);
        $db_host='localhost';
        $db_user='root';
        $db_pwd='';
        $conn=mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd,true);
        if(!$conn)
        {
            echo "Database connection Unsuccessful".mysql_error($conn)."<br>";
        }   
        else
        {
            echo "Database connection Successful"."<br>";
        }   
    //Creating a new database
        $sql="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_chkAJAX";
        if (mysql_query($sql,$conn))
        {
              echo "Database db_student created successfully"."<br>";
        } 
        else
        {
              echo "Error creating database: "."<br>";
        }
    //Creating a Table
        $dataselect=mysql_select_db("db_chkAJAX",$conn);
        if(!$dataselect)
        {
            die("Database not Selected".mysql_error()."<br>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Database Selected"."<br>";
        }
        $sql_create="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LoginRecord (Username varchar (50), Password varchar(15), MobileNumber bigint(10))";
        $qry=mysql_query($sql_create);
        if(!$qry)
        {
            die("Table not created".mysql_error()."<br>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Table Created Successfully"."<br>";
        }
    //Inserting values into table
        $data_insert="INSERT INTO LoginRecord(Username, Password, MobileNumber) VALUES('$usr_name', '$pwd', '$mob')";
        $data_insert_query=mysql_query($data_insert);
        if(!$data_insert_query)
        {
            die(" Unsuccessful data Insertion into table".mysql_error()."<br>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Data inserted into table successfully"."<br>";
        }
    //Closing the connection
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
    function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: What gives you the idea you messed up? Where is the error?

Comment: no error...but the onsubmit="return Validation(this)" doesnot work and i also tried making the variables global. What should i do so that the form doesnt get redirected if there are errors?.

Comment: Is this question so bad that someone need to down vote it? Or is it that some ppl just come and down vote everything they see? pff...

Comment: When you dump a large block of code and just say "fix this"/"what is wrong" you will often get downvoted or closed. Need to try and be more specific. What you clarified in the comment was good.

Comment: Your code is still vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: @Gumbo: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. It was really helpful. As a learner i always thought mysql_real_escape_string, stripslashes, trim and htmlspecialchars is enough to prevent injection! A request... can you please tell me why onsubmit="return validation(this)" doesnot work? I have told like Andrew said but still "function Validation()" never gets compiled...

Comment: @Altair44 Only `mysql_real_escape_string` is supposed for escaping data for being used in a MySQL string literal. The others have nothing to do with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

One problem, you are using html comments in your javascript instead of javascript comments, use //

http://www.jshint.com

Also, It looks like you need to set the check variables as global, since you are validating outside of the function that checks if they are valid.

I don't think you need to put `this` inside of `Validate()`

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: did like you said and also tried putting alerts in the "function validation()". None of the alert messages gets compiled. That function is totally ignored. i cannot understand why...